# Python code output redirect to file when code has raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have code which reads a parameter from user (username and password), does some processing, and prints the output to console.

Everything works fine until I try to redirect this output to a different file.

For example: test.py

```
input = raw_input("username = ")
print input
```

Using this script, if I try to redirect the output to different , don't see the prompt for username.

```
python test.py > output
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course not: you redirected that to the `output` file.  If you want two output channels, you need to program that; a simple redirection of all `stdout` won't do the job.  If you want to do this from Python, you can accept the `output` file as a command line parameter, open it within the Python script, and write the processed input to the file.  If you want to do that from your command shell, you'll still need to redefine the use of `stdout` at that level, so you have separate output channels.